Constrained Optimizer as Projection of Unconstrained Optimizer
Let $f:H\to \mathbb{R}$ be a once Fréchet differentiable strictly convex function on a separable Hilbert space and $C$ be a non-empty closed and convex body therein.  Let $P_C:H\to C$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $C$.
When does the following hold
$$
\tag{C}
P_C(x^{\star}) \in \operatorname{argmin}_{u\in C} f(u) 
$$
where
$$
\tag{U}
x^{\star}\in \operatorname{argmin}_{x\in H} f(x)
.
$$
i.e. let $u^{\star}:=P_C(x^{\star})$ and suppose that $x^{\star}\not\in C$.  I want to show that $u^{\star}$ is optimal for the constrained problem

So Far:
My reasoning is that an optimizer of the constrained problem must satisfy the fixed-point condition
$$
u^{\star} = P_C(u^{\star}- \alpha\nabla f(u^{\star}))
$$
for all $\alpha>0$; if $f$ is Fréchet differentiable.
Now, if $x^{\star}\in C$ is an optimizer to the unconstrained problem, we are done since:
$$
f(x^{\star})=0 \mbox{ and } \Pi_C(x^{\star})=x^{\star}.
$$
Suppose that $x^{\star}\not\in C$.
Since $x^{\star}\not\in C$ and $f$ is strictly convex then $P_C(x^{\star})$ is not optimal.  Therefore, $P_C(x^{\star})-\nabla f(P_C(x^{\star})\not \in C$; thus it lies on the line segment
$$
L:=\{P_C(x^{\star}) + t(x^{\star}-P_C(x^{\star})) :\, t\ge 0\}
$$
note that $L\cap C=\emptyset$.
By definition of the orthogonal projection $P_C$ we have that
$P_C(x^{\star})\in L$.  Thus, $P_C(x^{\star})$ and $f(P_C(x^{\star})$ both belong to the same line segment, $L$.  Hence, so does $x^{\star}-\alpha\,\nabla f(P_C(x^{\star})$ for all $\alpha>0$.
Consequentially,
$$
P_C\big(x^{\star}-\nabla f(P_C(x^{\star})\big) = x^{\star}.
$$
Is this argument correct/what am I missing (if so, do things change if $C$ is the closed unit ball)?

Related: This post.

Almost everything that follows after ``Since $x^\not\in C$ ...'' makes no sense to me. Why is $P_C(x^)$ not optimal? Why should $P_C(x^) - \nabla f(P_C(x^))\not \in C$? why should it lie on the line segment? etc

At the end, you conclude that $P_C($somthing$)=x^$, which implies $x^\in C$ This is  a contradiction to the assumption $X^*\not\in C$.

The claim is true if $H$ is one-dimensional.
The claim does not hold in general. Here is a counterexample.
Take $H=\mathbb R^2$, $C=\{ x\in \mathbb R^2: \ x_2=0\}$.
Define
$$
f(x) = (x_1-x_2)^2 +  (x_1+x_2-2)^2.
$$
Then $x^* = (2,2)$. The minimum of $f$ on $C$ is at $(1,0,) \ne P_C(x^*) = (2,0)$.

Do you know what class of convex sets this holds for?  Does now require a type of symmetry in $C$?

No idea. ${}{}{}{}$
